# How to specify matching a literal asterisk in a json schema pattern

Tags: json, regex, json-schema-validator, ajv

I want to specify a pattern in a json schema that would require an asterisk at the beginning of a string that can only contain 2 characters such as:

```
*A
```

I have tried the following pattern but it does not work:

```
"code": {
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^[*A-Z]{2}$"
}
```

The above pattern allows: *A and AA which is not what I want.

I am using the ajv json schema validator.

Answer (score 3):

The regex `[*A-Z]{2}` matches either `*`, or `A-Z`. Asterisks are a bit odd, so you need to make it its own group. Try this out: `^[*][A-Z]{2}$`

Edit: I'm assuming you mean it needs an asterisk followed by 2 characters, like `*BC` or `*AE`. If you mean it must start with an asterisk followed by exactly one character, just remove the `{2}`.

Comment: It's not needed to put `*` in brackets. A back-escape is sufficient to escape any special character (and then another backslash for the JSON encoding).

Comment: I tried all of the suggested comments and I  ended up using this"pattern": "^\\*[A-Z]$" . This pattern also works: "pattern": "^[*][A-Z]$" . For some  reason it does not show the second backslash when I save my edit. Thank you all very much !

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern `^[*A-Z]{2}$` allows 2 times either an asterix, or a character in the range A-Z

If you want to allow 2 characters, and the first has to be an asterix:

```
^\*[A-Z]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bOdXGm/1)